# How can I directly access my base class property in the derived class without using methods or constructors?

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
class Animal
    {
        public bool isHungry { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }    
class Dog : Animal
    {
        Age = 5; //Gives error, "Age doesnt exist in current context"
        public Dog()
        {
            Age = 5;//Works fine
            Console.WriteLine("Dog");
        }
    }
```

I want to access the public properties directly, is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code must be within methods - if you want to set a default value for all `Dog` instances then the constructor is the proper place to do that.

You *could* make the base property virtual and then override it in `Dog` with a default value:

```
class Animal
{
    public bool isHungry { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}    
class Dog : Animal
{
    public override int Age {get; set;} = 5; 
    public Dog()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dog");
    }
}
```

but that seems like overkill in this simple example.

Answer (score 0):

D Stanley is totally right. Another way to do it is to use `new` keyword. This is a little bit cleaner in my opinion but totally depends on the context and problem.

```
class Dog : Animal
{
    public new int Age = 5;
}
```

Comment: The problem with `new` is that you now have _two_ `Age` properties (actually one property and one field) that will have different values in different contexts. it _might_ be the right solution for the actual problem but there are larger consequences than just "cleanliness".

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, not all animals would have the same age (*5 in this case*). Set your properties via the constructor, or if they have public setters, instantiate an instance of `Dog` and then set its `Age` property.

```c#
public abstract class Animal
{
    protected Animal()
    {
    }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}    

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog(int age)
    {
        this.Age = age;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{nameof(Dog)}: {nameof(Age)} - {this.Age}";
    }
}
```